# TypeError: undefined is not a function--I don't see what function is undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a recursive program that starts from 1 and finds a possible sequence of either adding 5 or multiplying by 3 to reach an integer argument that is given, and I keep getting the error "TypeError: undefined is not a function."

Thank you for any help!

```js
var ii; var current_array; var target;
function puzzle(target, current_array) {
  if (current_array==undefined)
    current_array=[];
  var current_array=current_array;
  var current_total=1;
  for (ii=0;ii<current_array.length;ii++) {
    if (current_array[ii]==3)
      current_total*=3;
    else current_total+=5;
  }
  if (current_total>target)
    return null;
  else if (current_total==target){
    return current_array;
  }
  else {return puzzle(target, current_array.push(3))||
    puzzle(target, current_array.push(5));
       }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where exactly does the error occur?

Comment: Wow, at line 5 you have 3 instances of the `current_array` variable! The global, the function argument, and the local one... That's confusin!

Comment: @RyanFoley, apply format to code  for your description and remove thanks

Comment: @LcSalazar `current_array=current_array` just in case.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say based on your code sample but I'd try to use typeof to test for the undefined variable:

```
if (typeof(current_array) === 'undefined')
  current_array = [];
```

Comment: you would have to use `typeof(current_array) === 'undefined'` as typeof returns a string